# Silk Test - PressItem alternative with Open Agent

Tags: silktest

I need to move all my scripts from Classic to Open Agent and I faced with one problem and dont know how to fix. I have some TreeView where need to rightclick on selected item, before where used PressItem(TreeView.GetSelItem(),2) 
But now whole treeview moved to Open Agent declaration and PressItem function is not supported by OA.
Using keyboard is not a solution, because "application" button is not working in that treeview.

Is there any solutions to open context/drop-down menu from selected item?

Comment: Fixed by using GetItemRect + GetSelText + OpenContextMenu

Comment: Can you please add that as answer and accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using GetItemRect + GetSelText + OpenContextMenu